# Printing out database results in alphabetical categories

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pick up records from database and print them out in alphabetical fashion so it would show

'#' Records

- %@$ Records
- %$%^£@ Records

'A' Records

- A record
- A record

Hope that makes sense, I could do this via PHP but this would be rather complicated and would require a lot of code, is there a way to do this via DB and few lines of PHP?

This needs to pick up first letter of the entry, if its in alphabet, it would put it under correct letter, if its not, it would put it under '#'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourField DESC
```

This will take items in a given field and order them in a "descending" manner (i.e. alphabetical).

For grouping, look into creating PHP arrays. A sample would be something like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($query_results as $key => $val) {
  $letter = substr($val, 1); // First letter
  $arr[$letter][] = $val;
}
```

and from there you can use the PHP array. If something goes wrong with the sort, PHP does have sort array functions (one-line functions) which can fix such issues.

Comment: I know that much, i need to group them up somehow so I can go through the different letters

Answer (score 0):

To order by (and retrieve) first letter as well as full name, collapsing non-alpha characters to '#" in pure MySQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN name NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]' THEN '#'
    ELSE SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR 1)
  END AS first_letter, 
  name 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY first_letter, name DESC
```

*(note: top-of-head code is untested)*